# What wrong on my code with PDO insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I try insert data to database but i always got error

```
$insertTransaction = $odb->prepare("INSERT INTO `cq9_transactions` VALUES(NULL, :userId, :actionType, :account, :createTime, :endTime, :statusTxt, :statusMessage, :beforeBalance, :afterbalance, :currencyCode, :eventJSON, :createdAt, NULL)");
$insertTransaction->execute(array(':userId' => 1, ':actionType' => 'takeall', ':account' => 'admin', ':createTime' => getDateTime(), ':endTime' => getDateTime(), ':statusTxt' => 'success', ':statusMessage' => 'success', ':beforeBalance' => '1', ':afterBalance' => '1', ':currencyCode' => 'CNY', ':eventJSON' => '1', ':createdAt' => serverDateTime()));
```

Error Message:
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\cq9-api\public\index.php on line 120

Comment: The error message is clear, no? You have too many or too few parameters. Compare the parameters in your query with `execute()`.

Comment: You have a simple typo error with one of your parameters..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert 14 values into your table and you have executed only 12 value. Try to modify your execute() or insert statement.